# How to securely transfer on-premise data to GCS buckets daily

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What is the best way to securely transfer data to GCS bucket from on-premise. Data   size in 10GBs to transferred daily to GCS buckets.
Data is lying on my on-premise server in my organisation.
Is there SFTP kinda protocol available there.

Comment: Unlike other cloud provides, Google does not offer a SFTP protocol to their GCS backend. You might vote for it here: https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302604-cloud-storage/suggestions/36119881-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-gcs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to do this. Data are transferred over HTTPS, and depending on your security requirements there are [various options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption) for controlling encryption keys used for storing data.